# Checking multiple mutually exclusive options in perl's getopt

Tags: perl

How to check than only one of `-a` or `-b` or `-c` is defined?

So not together `-a -b`, nor `-a -c`, nor `-b -c`, nor `-a -b -c`.

Now have

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Carp;
use Getopt::Std;

our($opt_a, $opt_b, $opt_c);
getopts("abc");

croak("Options -a -b -c are mutually exclusive")
        if ( is_here_multiple($opt_a, $opt_c, $opt_c) );

sub is_here_multiple {
        my $x = 0;
        foreach my $arg (@_) { $x++ if (defined($arg) || $arg); }
        return $x > 1 ? 1 : 0;
}
```

The above is working, but not very *elegant*.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/888864/869025) is the similar question already, but this is different, because checking *two* exclusive values is easy - but here is multiple ones.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Or you can:

```
die "error" if ( scalar grep { defined($_) || $_  } $opt_a, $opt_b, $opt_c  ) > 1;
```

The grep in scalar context returns the count of matched elements.

Comment: The `>` enforces scalar context anyway, and there is no need for the `defined` check, so this could be `die "error" if grep($_, $opt_a, $opt_b, $opt_c) > 1`

Answer (score 1):

```
sub is_here_multiple { ( sum map $_?1:0, @_ ) > 1 }
```

`sum` is provided by [List::Util](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?List%3a%3aUtil).

---

Oh right, `grep` counts in scalar context, so all you need is

```
sub is_here_multiple { ( grep $_, @_ ) > 1 }
```

Comment: it throwing "syntax error at xx line 9, near "sum map". "sum" - comes from where? perldoc -f sum don't know it.

Comment: Says the person loading Carp. Which one do you think is a "big module". Anyway, feel free to write your own `sum`.